# Substring to take all letters after the 4th character

Tags: php, string, substring

I only have a basic understanding of substring. I am trying to extract the first 4 characters as a string variable and extract the rest of the characters in another string variable. How may I do this with substring? With PHP

```
$rest = substr("jKsuSportTopics", -3, 1);
$rest2 = substr("jKsuSportTopics", 4, 0);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The second argument is the starting index, and the third argument is the length of the string. If the 3rd argument is missing, you'll get the rest of the string.

```
$first_part = substr("jKsuSportTopics", 0, 4);
$rest = substr("jKsuSportTopics", 4);
```

Here's a quote from [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

> ...the returned string will start at the `start`'th position in `string`, counting from zero. For instance, in the string 'abcdef', the character at position 0 is 'a', the character at position 2 is 'c', and so forth.
>
> [...]
>
> If `length` is given and is positive, the string returned will contain at most `length` characters beginning from `start` (depending on the length of string).
>
> [...]
>
> If `length` is omitted, the substring starting from `start` until the end of the string will be returned.